# Where is the right place to ask about creating packages?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to learn to create a Linux package from source.
I would like to create package for CentOS, but maybe I could ask a more generic question.

Where is the right place to ask this?

Comment: @hims056 How is it so that you can edit my question without my approval? Just curious.

Comment: There is [a privilege](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to edit other's Q&A. Only users with less than 2k can *suggest* edits on other's posts.

Comment: It's really easy to end up asking a question that is too broad. I can't talk about CentOS but Debian has extensive documentation about how to create packages. My advice here is the usual one: read the doc, try something and when it fails and you can't find a solution, ask about *this* problem. And focusing on a specific problem might suggest one site over another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site is *probably* the best place for specific questions about Linux packaging.

(Of course, if the question is mostly code-related, it probably belongs on Stack Overflow instead. And be sure to formulate a specific question about a problem you're having, rather than asking a vague "How do I package things for Linux?" type question...)